# How to center BusyIndicator to the center of MainWindow?

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit

I created sample Wpf application and installed Extended WPF Toolkit (NuGet package). Here's my xaml code for showing BusyIndicator.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp3.Progress"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        WindowStyle="None"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Title=""
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
        d:DesignWidth="300" 
        d:DesignHeight="300">
    <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"></xctk:BusyIndicator>
</Window>
```

Showing the progress window is triggered with this code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Progress w = new Progress
  {
    Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow,
    WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
  };
  w.Show();
}
```

My question is simple. How to show BusyIndicator in the middle of the MainWindow screen. As Shown from the picture below it's not centered as it should be. Note that I use `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

[image]

Comment: This is such a basic thing instead of trying to figure out how to use it why dont you create it yourself?

Comment: Create what myself. A spinner control? If it's such a basic thing, could you provide a basic answer

Comment: extToolkit:BusyIndicator 
seems to be just a border with a textbox and a progressbar.
if you create that yourself you have full control over it. But when using an external toolkit you need to rely on it to be correct, the nameing to be standardisted etc. It makes sence to get externals for complex things in my eyes to save time but if all you want to do is display a progress bar you should rely on and advance your personal skill. Might be a personal opinion...

Comment: @DenisSchaf I agree, but like you mentioned if you have the time. One more thing is that BusyIndicator is used all over the application. Although by trying different things with xaml, you get some basic knowledge how Xaml behaves. Although some things about rendering are and will be a mistery to me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by removing `Window.SizeToContent` property and by adding `VerticalAlignment` and `HorizontalAlignment` properties to BusyIndicator (actually now I used spinner, but this doesn't make any difference in solution).

```
<Window x:Class="Test.Progress"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:extToolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit/extended"
        WindowStyle="None"
        AllowsTransparency="True"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Title=""
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
        ShowInTaskbar="False"
        Background="Transparent" 
        d:DesignWidth="200" 
        d:DesignHeight="200"
        MaxWidth="250"
        MaxHeight="250">
  <xctk:BusyIndicator IsBusy="True"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"></xctk:BusyIndicator>
</Window>
```

The problem is because `BusyIndicator` [was not designed to use it in separate window](https://elegantcode.com/2011/10/07/extended-wpf-toolkitusing-the-busyindicator/)

> The BusyIndicator is a ContentControl.  What this means is that the BusyIndicator can contain a single child element within it?s open and closing tags.

Additionally if you do, first thing that is shown is small ui control (12x12 pixels) and after some latency finally the progress bar/busy indicator is shown.

By specifying `SizeToContent='WidthAndHeight'`, xaml automatically resizes height and width relative to content. In this case (12x12) ui control is taken, and after some latency time finally as mentioned above busy indicator is shown. But by that time, the xaml ui renderer already applied `SizeToContent` and therefore you would have to manually re-position the progress bar.

I'm not really sure how xaml ui renderes works without specifying `SizeToContent`, but apparently it re-positions the busy indicator correctly after it is shown.

Answer (score 3):

Having a seperate window to display the busy indicator and will  result in unwanted behaviour. What happens if the original window is maximised, moved etc.?

Consider adding the busy indicator to the main screen. Usually I create an overlay region that is used to display message dialogs, progress bars etc..

```
<Window>
<Grid>
<Application stuff ....>
</Application stuff>
  <ContentControl regions:RegionManager.RegionName="OverlayRegion"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I'm using Prism here but you can replace the ContentControl with anything, such as the BusyIndicator and manipulate the visibility of the control.